# Adding SignalR to a Web Application already running Websockets

Tags: websocket, signalr

I am working with an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC 5 web application in Visual Studio 2022. The solution consists of multiple projects with one of them having websocket integration for a Twilio SMS chat. The websockets/Twilio integration was written years ago by another developer.

Recently I was asked to make some changes to the application's Administrative Dashboard that require the server to update all client browsers. I would like to incorporate SignalR for this, but I'm unable to get it to run. Basically, the auto-generated proxy does not get created - I get the /signalr/hubs folder (file?), but it is empty which results in an HTTP 404.

After way too much time trying to get it to work, I created a new Project with the bare bones needed for SignalR. It wouldn't work either.

When I changed the SignalR Project URL port number to something other than what the main websockets application runs on, it works flawlessly.

Is it possible to run a Microsoft.Websockets web application on the same server:port with another web application running SignalR?

If this is possible, how might I do it?